# Unable to update repository on github

Tags: git, github, terminal

I'm new to Git and Github. I created a repository but am unable to add files and update it on the Terminal.

So far the only thing that has worked is `$ git add .`

When I try to do  `$ git push`  it says:

> error: failed to push  some refs to 'git@github.com:emailadress'

When I try to do `$ git pull` it says:

> You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).

When I try to do `$ git status` it says:

> Changes to be committed:
>
> modified: .DS_Store
>
> modified: README

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `git add .` did you then commit your added files? Something along the lines of `git commit -am "Initial commit"`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it fixed it. Would it be too much to ask if you could explain what that line does?

Comment: Sure, but it's pretty fundamental to how git works so I would definitely recommend looking at the [git tutorial](http://schacon.github.com/git/gittutorial.html). Basically, you're telling git to "save" any changes you've made in your git repository. You added files to be tracked with `git add .` and need to save that change (you added files) with `git commit`. You can find help on specific commands like this: `git help commit`